# Sum and product of k real numbers > 0 is unique?

Tags: combinatorics, conjectures, arithmetic-combinatorics

Can we prove that $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i$ is unique for $x_i \in R > 0$?
I stated that conjecture to solve CS task, but I do not know how to prove it (or stop using it if it is false assumption).

Is the pair of Sum and Product of array of k real numbers > 0 unique per array? I do not want to find underlying numbers, or reverse this pair into factorisation. I just assumed that pair is unique per given set to compare two arrays of equal length to determine whether numbers inside with possible multiplicities are the same. The order in array does not matter. 0 is discarded to give meaningful sum and product.

At the input I get two arrays of equal length, one of which is sorted, and I want to determine if the elements with multiplicities are the same, but I do not want to sort the second array (this will take more than linear time, which is the objective).
So I thought to make checksums, sum and product seemed unique to me, hence the question.

For example:
I have two arrays: v=[1,3,5,5,8,9.6] and the second g=[9.6,5,3,1,5,8].
I calculate sum = 31.6, and product = 5760. For both arrays, since one is sorted version of another.
And now I calculate this for b=[1,4,4,5,8,9.6], sum is 31.6 but product is 6144.
So I assumed that if both sum and product are not the same for two given arrays, than the element differs.

Getting back to question, I am thinking that the pair {sum, product} is the same for all permutations of array (which is desired), but will change when elements are different (which is maybe wishfull thinking).

Comment: You had really better give some examples of what you are talking about, with numbers. If you mean that knowledge of the sum and product tells you what the $k$ numbers are, this is true for $k=2$ but false for $k \geq 3.$

Comment: EvilJS, please invent two arrays of length 4, type them in your question, then show us what calculation you are doing with the two arrays and what conclusions you get. Actual numbers. Please.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I came up with the same question trying to encode Sudokus as polynomials. I wonder if it is true that n numbers which are all integers from $1$ to $n$ whose product is $n!$ and whose sum is $n (n+1) / 2$ are necessarily the integers $1$ through $n$.

Comment: ... and it's not true, for example ( 9 9 7 5 4 4 4 2 1 ) has the same product and sum as the integers 1..9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true when $k=1$ or $k=2$.

It is also true when $k>2$. But only if the sum is $A$ and the product is $(\frac{A}{k})^k$ (which, by AM-GM is the maximum possible product with fixed sum $A$).

To see why it isn't true in any other case:

Consider the family of tuples:

$(\frac{a-n}{k-1},\frac{a-n}{k-1}\dots ,\frac{a-n}{k-1},n)$ their sum is clearly $A$. moreover, when $n=0$ the product is $0$ and when $n$ is $\frac{a}{k}$ the product is $(\frac{a}{k})^k$. So by continuity we can find a tuple with product $x$ for $x\in(0,(\frac{a}{k})^k)$.

Now consider the family of tuples:

$(\frac{a-2n}{k-2},\frac{a-2n}{k-2}\dots ,\frac{a-2n}{k-2},n,n)$ their sum is clearly $A$. moreover, when $n=0$ the product is $0$ and when $n$ is $\frac{a}{k}$ the product is $(\frac{a}{k})^k$. So by continuity we can find a tuple with product $x$ for $x\in(0,(\frac{a}{k})^k)$.

So for every product and sum we can find at least two distinct tuples (one from each family).

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the counterproof, that I was looking for, but (embarassingly) I do not fully understand the answer. Taking it short - for every array you have provided equation for finding counterexamples? I think that if n=0 it would mean that 0 is valid element, but it was restricted.

Comment: Yes, so if you have sum $A$ and product $P$, we can find two arrays with sum $A$ and product $P$. Just to make it clearer, if the sum is $A>0$ then $P$ **has** to be in the interval $(0,\frac{A^k}{k^k}]$, otherwize there are zero arrays with sum $A$ and product $P$. now, if $P=\frac{A^k}{k^k}$, then your hypothesis is true. But if $P\neq\frac{A^k}{k^k}$ then we can find at least two different arrays with product $P$ and sum $A$.(and they are completely different, they have no numbers in common).

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there chance that is such pair (tuple?) of operations that will identify that two arrays have the same elements uniquely? Like adding subtraction etc.? Or shall I discard pursuit?

Comment: maybe it would be easier if you shared the actual problem (your computer science problem) I'm a CS student myself.

Comment: Input: two arrays A and B of length n, where B is in sorted order.  
Query: do A and B contain the same items (with their multiplicity)? Could it be solved in deterministic linear time? (to this part I wanted to abandon comparisons, so checksum like linear algorithm would be great solution), but after your answer I think that for n elements there probably would be needed n constraints to be unique...

Comment: Is this acceptable https://gist.github.com/JorgeFernandezH/398726ed854f9ab5f80b ?

Comment: Hash table has expected O(1) complexity, although worst case is $n$ if we get lots of collisions, but expected runtime is $O(n)$.

Comment: Map has underneath self balancing tree or hashtable with expected (not deterministic) runtime so this comes to be NlogN or N^2 effectively ;) And pursuit is N. With collisions and worst case of retreival of element is n, so it is list, the effective runtime worst case is n^2, and the worst case should be linear, deterministic, not avg case.

Answer (score 3):

The roots of 
$$ x^3 - 15 x^2 + 59 x - 45   $$
are $(1,5,9).$
We know from the Vieta formulas (I think that is what people on this site call these) that $1 + 5 + 9 = 15$ and $1 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 = 45.$ The coefficient of $x$ keeps its sign, $1 \cdot 5 + 1 \cdot 9 + 5 \cdot 9 = 59.$

The roots of 
$$ x^3 - 15 x^2 + 60 x - 45   $$
are $(A,B,C).$
We know from the Vieta formulas (I think that is what people on this site call these) that $A + B + C = 15$ and $A \cdot B \cdot C = 45.$ ***However*** $A \cdot B + A \cdot C + B \cdot C = 60.$

The approximate numerical values are
$$ A =0.9700245237561371997892722247 , B = 5.335859021895927357611387648,$$  $$ C =  8.694116454347935442599340128  $$

Here is an example with four numbers, no need to use polynomial, just some square roots.

$$ \left( 3,5,7,11 \right) $$
$$ \left( 6 - \sqrt 3, \; 6 + \sqrt 3, \; 7 - \sqrt {14}, \; 7 + \sqrt {14} \right) $$
For both quadruples, the sum is $26$ and the product is $1155,$ since
$$ (6 - \sqrt 3) (6 + \sqrt 3) = 36 - 3 = 33 = 3 \cdot 11, $$
$$ (7 - \sqrt {14}) (7 + \sqrt {14}) = 49 - 14 = 35= 5 \cdot 7. $$

Wrote a little program, found an example of two sextuples with matching sum and product, just positive integers

```
1 2 3 4 9 10 sum 29 product 2160
1 2 3 5 6 12 sum 29 product 2160
```

This means that we could have used integers in triples,
$$ \color{blue}{ (4,9,10)} $$
$$ \color{red}{ (5,6,12)} $$
sums are $23$ and products are $360.$

Smallest sum for triples,

```
2 8 9 sum 19 product 144
3 4 12 sum 19 product 144
```

$$ \color{blue}{ (2,8,9)} $$
$$ \color{red}{ (3,4,12)} $$
sums are $19$ and products are $144.$

Comment: Sorry, did not understood at first. You have showed counterexample found by Viéta polynomials root connection?

Comment: Yes, using Vieta's formulas he can show that the roots for the same polynomial and the roots for the second polynomial have equal sum and product.

Comment: @dREaM added in an example of quadruples, just uses some square roots, no polynomials.

Comment: make it a comment, the two polynomials with these quadruples as roots are $x^4 - 26 x^3 + 236 x^2 - 886 x + 1155$ for 3,5,7,11 and then $x^4 - 26 x^3 + 236 x^2 - 882 x + 1155$ for the ones with the square roots. Very similar, slightly different linear coefficients.